# How do I run k3s within docker using the official rancher docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I want to start a server and a client using
 `docker run rancher/k3s:latest server` and
 `docker run -e K3S_TOKEN=xyz -e K3S_URL=https://<server_container_name>:6443 rancher/k3s:latest agent`

But for some reason, the server and the client aren't able to communicate with each other even if I deploy it on a separate network. Any suggestions as to what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting your first server, you would want to expose ports. Eg:

```
docker run -p 6443:6443 ranger/k3s:latest server
```

Then, make sure the other container can resolve the FQDN for your K3S_URL, sending this to the host address where your initial server was started on. Eg:

```
docker run --add-host <server_name>:<ip-address> \
    -e K3S_TOKEN=xyz -e K3S_URL=https://<server_name>:6443 \
    rancher/k3s:latest agent
```

Also note: in my case, I also had to add the `--privileged` docker option, and some `--snapshotter native` option

```
docker run --privileged -p 6443:6443 rancher/k3s:latest server --snapshotter native
docker run --privileged -e K3S_TOKEN=xxx --add-host=adcbd2a250ff:10.42.42.127 -e K3S_URL=https://adcbd2a250ff:6443 rancher/k3s:latest agent --snapshotter native
```